# Efficient Python/Pandas Selection and Sorting

Tags: python, pandas

My brother and I are working on reproducing the findings of [this paper](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2013/TakeuchiLee-ApplyingDeepLearningToEnhanceMomentumTradingStrategiesInStocks.pdf) where they use daily historical stock prices to predict future prices with incredibly high accuracy.

They used data from the center for research and security prices, but we are using data from quandl and are running into trouble with the runtimes for our preprocessing.  As in the paper, for each ticker and each day, we want to create a vector of 32 z-scores, comparing that ticker's momentum to the rest of the market's.  As an intermediate step, they create a vector of 32 cumulative returns for each stock over a given time period (12 for the previous 12 months and 20 for the previous 20 days.) (this process is also briefly discussed in section 2.2 of the paper)

Because of the large amount of data, we are having problems with runtimes simply creating these cumulative returns vectors. We imported the data from a 1.7gb csv and turned it into a Pandas dataframe. We then wrote a function to take a given ticker and date and create a cumulative returns vector.  I suspect that our trouble is in how we select data out of the dataframe. (specifically the following lines [each of them don't take much time, but they both need to be run many times for each date])

```
prices = data[data.ticker == ticker_argument]
```

and

```
p = prices[prices.date == date_argument]
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this considering that the data is sorted by ticker and the data for each ticker is also sorted by date?  I'd imagine that you could do some sort of binary search to speed most of it up, but should I do that by hand in plain python or is there a better pandas way to do that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The quandl csv is at http://www.jackmckeown.com/prices.csv if you want more info on how the data is formatted.

Comment: From what I understand, looks like you need to use `.groupby()` by ticker and date.

Comment: Have you profiled your code? I doubt that boolean indexing takes much time for 1.7gb of data. You also need to clarify what you mean by "having problems with runtimes". How long does it take?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if this question had less words and more sample code/data.  But one thing I suspect is sub-optimal:  you do repeated selections for each date and could probably speed things up by just doing ONE selection.  I.e. selecting a range of dates once should be much faster than selecting a single date multiple times.

Comment: I would load it onto SQL and do a parallel zscore computation in python.